# xunit pass class method as inline data

Tags: .net-core, xunit

Is it possible to pass an object method as inline data to a xunit test?

I have a few object methods to set some object state that I would like to pass to a [Theory] as [InlineData] like so:

```cs
private readonly SomeObject _sut;

public SomeConstructorForTests()
{
    _sut = new("foo", "bar");
}

[Theory]
[InlineData(_sut.MethodToSetState)]
[InlineData(_sut.SomeOtherMethodToSetState)]
public void some_test(Action set_pre_state)
{
// arrange
set_pre_state();

// act
...

// assert
...
}
```

Getting a syntax error at the inline data "_sut" --> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

I simply do not want to create a lost of tests when it should be possible to inline it, keep it DRY :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ClassData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/#using-a-dedicated-data-class-with-classdata-) for this. Annotate your method with

```
[Theory]
[ClassData(typeof(TestDataObject))]
```

and TestDataObject needs to extend `TheoryData<SomObject>`.

You can then call `Add(new SomeObject("foo", "bar"))` in the constructor of the TestData class.